# Property decorators in Python and set functions

Tags: python, properties, get, set, decorator

I have some questions regarding the following code:

```
  1 class Test(object):
  2     def __init__(self):
  3         print "Object instance created."
  4         self._x = raw_input("Initial value of x = ")
  5         print "Initial value of x set."
  6 
  7     def Property(func):
  8         return property(**func())
  9 
 10     @Property
 11     def x():
 12         def fget(self):
 13             print 'Getting x'
 14             return self._x
 15         def fset(self, val):
 16             print 'Setting x'
 17             self._x = val
 18         def fdel(self):
 19             print 'Deleting x'
 20             del self._x
 21         doc = "A test case"
 22         return locals()
```

1. Why is the `Property()` function necessary?
2. Why can't I just `return locals()` and then use `@property` as a decorator directly?

When I do that I get an error saying x takes no arguments, one given (presumably 'self'). I know python has the `@x.setter` option, however I'm forced to use 2.4 regularly, so it's not an option for me. Even then, `@x.setter` still seems less elegant than defining it all in one block.

Is there a way to define it all in one block using `@property`?

Comment: I actually like your work-around -- I may start using it!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `property` as a decorator directly for the code you have posted because it was not designed to be used that way, and it won't work.

If used as a decorator, `property` converts the function into the getter;  if used as a function, you can pass in the getter, setter, deleter, and a doc.

`locals()` returns *all* the locals, so you would have a dictionary with `fget`, `fset`, `fdel`, `doc`, `Property`, and `__init__` -- causing `property` to blow up because it was passed too many arguments.

Personally, I like the `@x.setter` and `@x.deleter` style, as I don't end up with unnecessary function names in the class name space.

If you have to use 2.4 regularly, just roll your own (or steal the latest from 2.6 like I did ;):

```
    class property(object):
        "2.6 properties for 2.5-"    
        def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
            self.fget = fget
            self.fset = fset
            self.fdel = fdel
            self.__doc__ = doc or fget.__doc__
        def __call__(self, func):
            self.fget = func
            if not self.__doc__:
                self.__doc__ = fget.__doc__
        def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
            if obj is None:
                return self         
            if self.fget is None:
                raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
            return self.fget(obj)
        def __set__(self, obj, value):
            if self.fset is None:
                raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
            self.fset(obj, value)
        def __delete__(self, obj):
            if self.fdel is None:
                raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
            self.fdel(obj)
        def setter(self, func):
            self.fset = func
            return self
        def deleter(self, func):
            self.fdel = func
            return self
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the best way without `@x.setter` and `@x.deleter` might be to just not use `property` as a decorator. It uses fewer lines than the hack in my first post to just say `x = property(xget, xset, xdel, xdoc)` and define the three functions in the class. I think that's what I'll end up doing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it all in one block: not by using `@property` by defining and instantiating a class that has `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()` methods.  See [Implementing Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) for more details:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Object instance created."
        self._x = raw_input("Initial value of x = ")
        print "Initial value of x set."
    class x(object):
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            print 'Getting x'
            return instance._x
        def __set__(self, instance, value):
            print 'Setting x'
            instance._x = value
        def __delete__(self, instance):
            print 'Deleting x'
            del instance._x
        __doc__ = "A test case"
    x = x()
```

`property()` is a shortcut for writing the above, and the `Property()` method in your example class is a shortcut for having to write the functions separately and pass them to `property()`; instead you write a function that defines the functions, then returns them, where they get passed to `property()`.

The reason you can't use `@property` is that decorators decorate a single object. So you'd need a container, such as a class, and so you might as well just write a descriptor directly at that point.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I wouldn't do it this way myself: `x` has to be instantiated, and it's clear at the end -- decorators were partly created to keep the instantiation close to the function/class definition where it wouldn't be easily missed.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda cringed writing `x = x()`. Even worse would have been `x = X(); del X` ...